# Some links keeps redirecting to another domain

Tags: redirect

Somebody worked on this project prior to me and for some reason decided to redirect many links to another site which no longer exists.

I deactivated all redirect plugins. One of which was "Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin" which had rules pointing to that domain. But for some reason it is still redirecting for those urls.

Is there a way to flush out these redirects? How can I track down what is causing redirects?

Note: redirects are NOT set up on the web hosting so it should be all wordpress.

I also searched the SQL tables for the domain and there are no entries...

Comment: First use a header check tool to make sure you're not cached - I use http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php . Then if they really are still redirecting, try deactivating all plugins (not just redirection plugins) and switch to a default theme. Then use header check again to verify the redirects are gone. From there, switch themes and check - activate one plugin and check - this way you can isolate what theme or plugin is causing redirects.

Comment: Make sure there are no redirects in the .htaccess file